# How to use bundler gem binaries in path

Tags: ruby, cucumber, bundler

I just started using bundler for gem packaging in vendor/. The problem is with certain gems (like rspec and cucumber) that have binaries. The binary path that is under my_app/vendor/gems/ruby/1.8/...cucumber-0.6.2/bin/  is not in my path, therefore when I go to run cucumber i get command cannot be found.

What is the easiest way to execute the bundled gem binaries from within the app rather than adding a large number of folders to my path?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so symlinking was in fact a daft idea. This question did get me thinking though, and I found this: http://litanyagainstfear.com/blog/2009/10/14/gem-bundler-is-the-future/

> Bundler will also dump gem executables in your Rails.root/bin directory. This means you can then use bin/rake, for example.

so, from the Rails root, does `bin/cucumber` work?

Comment: I thought about doing that, it just seems odd to have a git repository folder symlinked into usr/local/bin

Comment: that does! I actually know Nick and had read his blog post before but didn't pick up on that part. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately this is no longer accurate in bundler 0.9. But if you're still using bundler 0.8, this should work great.

Answer (score 7):

Newer version of bundler have an "exec" action. So for cucumber it would be:

```
bundle exec cucumber
```